# How exactly does CHAP authentication work?

Tags: ppp

Let's assume that pppd returns following message:

```
 rcvd [CHAP Challenge id=0x1 <12345>, name = ""]
```

and password is "test". What string should I use to calculate MD5 hash for CHAP Response?
[https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/wan/point-to-point-protocol-ppp/25647-understanding-ppp-chap.html] - here there is general description. But I still miss the details... I know that I should concatenate challenge, ID and password, but what is the correct order of concatenating those strings? Should I convert password from ASCII to hex before calculating hash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CHAP is defined in [RFC 1994](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1994).

You concatenate the identifier, the password (secret), and the challenge, in ASCII, in that order. The response is `hashMD5(identifier.secret.challenge)`, sent in binary (16 bytes for MD5).

For your example, that should be in hex `0x017465737412345` hashed.

Note that MD5 is not cryptographically safe any more due to advances in processing power and methods. On an unsafe channel, you'll need to provide additional password protection (like SSL/TLS or VPN).

Comment: Thank you. Could you please confirm if my understanding is correct? Following the example from my question, the string will contain following parts:
0x1 (interpreted as binary data),
test,
0x12345 (interpreted as binary data, so there is a mistake in my example, it should be even number of characters)

Comment: I think `12345` is rather a string than a hex number. The challenge has an arbitrary length, so it's a string. The ID must be the same byte as in the challenge - I've added that to the answer.

Comment: I found example with pppd logs 
[here](https://serverfault.com/questions/80592/pppd-chap-authentication-failure-sometimes).
` [CHAP Challenge id=0x3 <bf2b15282cf4f6672f1b809a251bd731>, name = "HiPer"]
[CHAP Response id=0x3 <69cd88a27098f6c3e961f49f0cec74fb>, name = "Sunrise"]`
The password was 'freesurf'.
Using [online hex to MD5 converter](https://cryptii.com/pipes/md5-hash) following string gave me the same response as in the logs: 036672656573757266bf2b15282cf4f6672f1b809a251bd731.
So it seems pppd returns data in hex format. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome - don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you.